# How to redirect to another directoy with htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

So here is the situation. My project (`myproject.uz`) contains many folders that are located in the root folder. For example, let’s say that there are 4 folders `api, backend, active, and terminal` that are places in the root. 
Traditionally, in order to open one of the folders, I will have to type `www.myproject.uz/api` in the browser so that I can access that specific folder. Is there a way to link one specific folder that would open up automatically once I type in `www.myproject.uz`.
For example, every time a user enters `www.myproject.uz`, folder c opens up automatically. At the same time I need that a user to see only `**www.myproject.uz**` instead of `www.myproject.uz/terminal`. The “invisibility” property must be applied only to one single folder.

How do I do that?

```
www/
    backend/
    active/
    api/
    terminal/
    index.php
    ...
```

My vhosts configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin adminboy@gmail.com
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "f:/Apache/home/myproject/www"
    ServerAlias  "myproject.uz" "www.myproject.uz" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think url-manager is better than .htaccess. You can redirect users every where in url-manager.

Comment: @hamed can you post link for example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!terminal/).*) terminal/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will open `/terminal/` for entering `http://www.domain.com` in browser.